# Undeclared variables in callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, variables

I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around this one.

I have a mouseover function, that sets two variables to the current margin-top and margin-left css properties, then executes an animation.  On mouseout, I wish to recall both those these two variables, but I continuously get an "variable is undefined" error...

```
$("#featInstructors li a").mouseover(function() {
  var mTop = $(this).find("img.instructor").css("margin-top");
  var mLeft = $(this).find("img.instructor").css("margin-left");
  $(this)
    .find("img.instructor")
    .animate({
      width: "115px",
      height: "115px",
      top: "50%",
      left: "50%",
      marginTop: "-57.5px",
      marginLeft: "-57.5px"}, 200);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
      $(this)
        .find("img.instructor")
        .animate({
          width: "200px",
          height: "200px",
          top: "0",
          left: "0",
          marginTop: mTop,
          marginLeft: mLeft
        }, 200);
    });
});
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you get the "variable is undefined" error on mouseover or mouseout?

Comment: @Dan O, I get the undefined on the mouseout.

Comment: @Colin DeClue, no that is correct. I wish for the marginTop and marginLeft of that image to be reverted to it's original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mTop;
var mLeft;

$("#featInstructors li a").mouseover(function() {
  mTop = $(this).find("img.instructor").css("margin-top");
  mLeft = $(this).find("img.instructor").css("margin-left");
$(this)
.find("img.instructor")
.animate({
  width: "115px",
  height: "115px",
  top: "50%",
  left: "50%",
  marginTop: "-57.5px",
  marginLeft: "-57.5px"}, 200);
})
.mouseout(function() {
  $(this)
    .find("img.instructor")
    .animate({
      width: "200px",
      height: "200px",
      top: "0",
      left: "0",
      marginTop: mTop,
      marginLeft: mLeft
    }, 200);
});
});
```

dont tried but probably this work

or this

```
.mouseout(function(a,b) {
  $(this)
    .find("img.instructor")
    .animate({
      width: "200px",
      height: "200px",
      top: "0",
      left: "0",
      marginTop: a,// mTop
      marginLeft: b//mLeft
    }, 200);
});
```

Comment: placing the variables OUTSIDE of the entire function did the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: Just a note - You can write the function in one line var mTop, mLeft; Also he just beat me in answering, just made the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/83sp523h/ :)

Comment: Also you can add stop() before animate to prevent bubbling :)

Comment: Why would `mouseout` get passed the margin top and margin left in your second example?

Answer (score 2):

Your indentation is wrong. When I ran your code through [jsbeauifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org/) it results in this:

```
$("#featInstructors li a").mouseover(function() {
        var mTop = $(this).find("img.instructor").css("margin-top");
        var mLeft = $(this).find("img.instructor").css("margin-left");
        $(this)
            .find("img.instructor")
            .animate({
                width: "115px",
                height: "115px",
                top: "50%",
                left: "50%",
                marginTop: "-57.5px",
                marginLeft: "-57.5px"
            }, 200);
    })
    .mouseout(function() {
        $(this)
            .find("img.instructor")
            .animate({
                width: "200px",
                height: "200px",
                top: "0",
                left: "0",
                marginTop: mTop,
                marginLeft: mLeft
            }, 200);
    });
});
```

You can see that the problem becomes obvious. The variables are declared inside the `mouseover` callback. You need to declare it first outside both functions:

```
var mTop, mLeft;

$("#featInstructors li a").mouseover(function() {
...
```

Comment: `this` doesn't have the same meaning outside of the function as it does inside of the function. This won't work.

Comment: @ColinDeClue I've updated the answer, though I see Profeta got to it first. Consider my answer an addition to theirs.